# $refs are null after route change

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have a keyboard navigation system. When you press ArrowUp or ArrowDown, an event is emitted FROM app.js (best place I found to listen to these keypresses since they need to be system-wide) TO the mounted() in the component.

The Event.$on() INSIDE the mounted() part of the component then calls a function that uses $refs to identify the currently selected item and, when ENTER is pressed, show it's modal.

app.js code (listen to the keypresses):

```
else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'ArrowDown' || event.key === 'Enter') {
            event.preventDefault()
            switch (this.$router.currentRoute.path) {
                case "/pedidos":
                    Event.$emit('navegarSetasPedidos', event.key)
                    break;
                case "/clientes":
                    Event.$emit('navegarSetasClientes', event.key)
                    break;
            }
        }
```

mounted() section of the component in question:

```
mounted() {

    Event.$on('navegarSetasPedidos', (key) => {this.navegarSetas(key)})
}
```

function responsible for the navigation (sorry for bad formating, haven't figured how stackoverflow's codeblock thing works yet):

```
navegarSetas(key) {
   if (this.navegacaoSetasAtiva == false) {
      this.navegacaoSetasAtiva = true
      this.navegacaoAtual = 0
   } else if (this.modalAtivado == false && this.navegacaoSetasAtiva == true) {
     if (key == 'ArrowDown' && this.navegacaoAtual < this.pedidos.length - 1) {
        this.navegacaoAtual++
        let elementoSelecionado = this.$refs['pedido'+this.navegacaoAtual][0].$el
        let boundaries = elementoSelecionado.getBoundingClientRect()
        if (boundaries.top < 0 || boundaries.top > (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)){
          elementoSelecionado.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'}) 
          }
       } else if (key == 'ArrowUp' && this.navegacaoAtual <= this.pedidos.length && this.navegacaoAtual > 0) {
         this.navegacaoAtual--
         let elementoSelecionado = this.$refs['pedido'+this.navegacaoAtual][0].$el
         let boundaries = elementoSelecionado.getBoundingClientRect()
         if (boundaries.top < 0 || boundaries.top > (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)){
            elementoSelecionado.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'}) 
           }
          } else if (key == 'Enter') {
            let pedidoSelecionado = this.pedidos[this.navegacaoAtual].id
              Event.$emit('changeShow', pedidoSelecionado)
            }
        }
```

This works very well the first time it is acessed. The problem is, if I change the current route to show another component and then return to the previous component, I get a lot of "this.$refs['pedido'+this.navegacaoAtual][0].$el is undefined" errors, but the system still works normally, albeit erratically.

The funny thing is: if I console log "this.$refs['pedido'+this.navegacaoAtual][0].$el is undefined", I'll get an EMPTY log before the errors, then ANOTHER one right below it, this time, not empty.

Everywhere else I've searched this says that the problem is due to how Vue re-renders things, and that I'm calling this event BEFORE it's rendered, which shouldn't be possible since I'm calling it inside mounted().

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, after a LOT of searching, the `Event.$on` event setters also work as the normal JavaScript ones (which makes a lot of sense now that I'm thinking about it)—meaning that you have to destroy them whenever your component is unmounted (aka Destroyed).

Even though VUE Dev Tools was picking only one event after the re-route, it was still firing two (seen through `console.log()` returning one empty value, a bunch of errors, and another value with filled array AFTER the errors).

The solution to this was simply adding `Event.$off('eventName')` on the `destroyed()` function of the component.